# ASP.net FFMPEG video conversion receiving error: "Error number -2 occurred"

Tags: asp.net, ffmpeg, flv, video-encoding, h.264

I am attempting to integrate FFMPEG into my asp.net website.  The process I am trying to complete is to upload a video, check if it is .avi, .mov, or .wmv and then convert this video into an mp4 using x264 so my flash player can play it.

I am using an http handler (ashx) file to handle my upload.  This is where I am also putting my conversion code.  I am not sure if this is the best place to put it, but I wanted to see if i could at least get it working.

Additionally, I was able to complete the conversion manually through cmd line.  The error -2 comes up when i output the standard error from the process I executed.

**This is the error i receive:**

FFmpeg version SVN-r23001, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers

built on May  1 2010 06:06:15 with gcc 4.4.2

configuration: --enable-memalign-hack --cross-prefix=i686-mingw32- --cc=ccache-i686-mingw32-gcc --arch=i686 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-avisynth --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libfaad --enable-pthreads --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libspeex --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libxvid --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopencore_amrnb

libavutil     50.15. 0 / 50.15. 0
  libavcodec    52.66. 0 / 52.66. 0
  libavformat   52.61. 0 / 52.61. 0
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libswscale     0.10. 0 /  0.10. 0

532010_Robotica_720.wmv: Error number -2 occurred

**here is the code below:**

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="VB" Class="upload" %>
```

Imports System
Imports System.Web
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Threading

Public Class upload : Implements IHttpHandler

```
Public currentTime As System.DateTime

Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

    currentTime = System.DateTime.Now

    If (Not context.Request.Files("Filedata") Is Nothing) Then
        Dim file As HttpPostedFile : file = context.Request.Files("Filedata")

        Dim targetDirectory As String : targetDirectory = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(context.Request("folder"))
        Dim targetFilePath As String : targetFilePath = Path.Combine(targetDirectory, currentTime.Month & currentTime.Day & currentTime.Year & "_" & file.FileName)

        Dim fileNameArray As String()
        fileNameArray = Split(file.FileName, ".")

        If (System.IO.File.Exists(targetFilePath)) Then
            System.IO.File.Delete(targetFilePath)
        End If

        file.SaveAs(targetFilePath)

        Select Case fileNameArray(UBound(fileNameArray))
                Case "avi", "mov", "wmv" 
                    Dim fileargs As String = 
                    fileargs = "-y -i " & currentTime.Month & currentTime.Day & 
                    currentTime.Year & "_" & file.FileName & " -ab 96k -vcodec libx264 
                    -vpre normal -level 41 "
                    fileargs += "-crf 25 -bufsize 20000k -maxrate 25000k -g 250 -r 20 
                    -s 900x506 -coder 1 -flags +loop "
                    fileargs += "-cmp +chroma -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 
                    -subq 7 -me_range 16 -keyint_min 25 "
                    fileargs += "-sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 
                    -rc_eq 'blurCplx^(1-qComp)' -bf 16 -b_strategy 1 -bidir_refine 1 "
                    fileargs += "-refs 6 -deblockalpha 0 -deblockbeta 0 -f mp4 " &   
                    currentTime.Month & currentTime.Day & currentTime.Year & "_" & 
                    file.FileName & ".mp4"

                    Dim proc As New Diagnostics.Process()
                    proc.StartInfo.FileName "ffmpeg.exe"
                    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = fileargs
                    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
                    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
                    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
                    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True

                    AddHandler proc.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf SaveTextToFile

                    proc.Start()
                    SaveTextToFile2(proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd())
                    proc.WaitForExit()
                    proc.Close()
            End Select

            context.Response.Write("1")

    End If

End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
        Return False
    End Get
End Property

Private Shared Sub SaveTextToFile(ByVal sendingProcess As Object, ByVal strData As DataReceivedEventArgs)

    Dim FullPath As String = "text.txt"
    Dim Contents As String = ""

    Dim objReader As StreamWriter
    objReader = New StreamWriter(FullPath)

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(strData.Data) Then
        objReader.Write(Environment.NewLine + strData.Data)
    End If

    objReader.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub SaveTextToFile2(ByVal strData As String)

    Dim FullPath As String = "texterror.txt"
    Dim Contents As String = ""

    Dim objReader As StreamWriter
    objReader = New StreamWriter(FullPath)

    objReader.Write(Environment.NewLine + strData)

    objReader.Close()

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

The issue was concerning permissions on the ffmpeg application itself.  Once I updated the permissions the error disappeared.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Could you give more details as to what permissions you updated?